# Can I use a makefile to make multiple executables with different #defines?

Tags: c, makefile

*edit:* I understand now that it is a standard practice in C, but I need to know how it is implemented. Could I get an example of a makefile implementing this? For instance, how do I indicate that the exe's should be named with a incrementing integer suffix? And where does the -DFOO: # go?

Like I said, I am reading the GNU make documentation, but it's thick.

*~edit*

I *think* what I want to do is possible, but the documentation is... heavy.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc_Rules

I need to be able to compile multiple executables from source, with each one using a different constant definition in the header. Think...

```
.exe1 needs to have
...#DEFINE FOO 2

.exe2 needs to have
...#DEFINE FOO 4

.exe3 needs to have
...#DEFINE FOO 16
```

To clarify, my program has the following headers:

```
#define DATASIZE 16777216 //16MB
#define NUM_PROCESS 10
#define NUM_COMPS   1
```

I wrote this bash script which I am using to measure performance of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5};
do
   ./usr/bin/time -p exe$1 >> exe_output$1 &2>1
done
```

As you can see, this is executed in the following way:

```
for i in {1..n};
do 
   ./run.sh $i
done
```

Where n is the number of executables I have compiled.

Now, in order to change the definitions (and therefore the performance) in each exe, I have to open up the source and change it by hand. I want to compile anywhere from 12 to 16 different executables, and doing it all by hand is getting tedious, so I'm looking for a way to do it programatically.

Comment: Put `-DFOO=2`, `-DFOO=4`, etc. in the compile commands for the different targets.

Comment: Certainly you can do it.  If you want an example you'll need to give more details.  I'm assuming that each `exe` is built from the same (or at least some overlapping) set of source files?  Do you want to build them all at the same time, or is it OK to build them one at a time (e.g., `make exe1`, `make clean`, `make exe2`, etc.)?

Comment: This is a standard technique used in nearly all C makefiles.  `-DFOO=1`

Comment: I wonder why this needs to be a `#define`, rather than a command-line argument to the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exe1: source.c
    $(CC) -DFOO=2 ... 

exe2: source.c
    $(CC) -DFOO=4 ...

exe3: source.c
    $(CC) -DFOO=16 ...
```

and so on, where `...` are the rest of your compile options.

Answer (score 1):

With a Makefile like this:

```
exe%: source.c
    $(CC) -DFOO=$(@:exe%=%) $^ -o $@
```

Which defines a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) to match everything starting with exe. It then uses a [substitution reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs) `$(@:exe%=%)` to extract the number for the define.

You can then use it in your bash script like this:

```
for i in {1..n};
do 
   make exe$i
   ./run.sh $i
done
```

and it will generate the needed executables on demand.

Comment: The `FOO` value is not the same as the number in the filename, so this won't work.

Comment: You could always use `for i in 2 4 16`. Which would of course mean that the exe name and its output file would be named according the the FOO value, but maybe that's a good thing? Maybe a bit more traceable...